# How to search combination of numbers in array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I need to search and print all the matches input numbers in a combination of numbers in an array.

My array looks like this:

```
$ar = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '25-27-32-34-37-42', '11-17-18-22-33-41'];
```

Here are the input and logic:

Given A: **01-05-24-30-35-36** (true, because it matches the exact combination numbers on array[0])

Given B: **05-30-01-36-35-24** (true, because the given 6 numbers are all present on array[0], different number position)

Given C: **01-05-24-30-35-33** (false, because the given 6 numbers are not present in one of the combinations of numbers in the array, even if the first 5 numbers are present but the last(33) is not then it will become false)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: [`explode()`](https://78.media.tumblr.com/1573221ff013cee41f7e6a238d4a57cd/tumblr_oogfgphUmd1qzlnwmo1_r1_1280.png) and then [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and then compare/count. Don't bother with regular expressions for this at all.

Comment: Good question. We wonder If you have tried any thing to show us.

Comment: Are all the combinations in `$ar` already sorted in ascending order like the ones in your example? Also, if I answer the question, will you share your lotto winnings with me? ;)

Comment: @Sammitch your comment gives me an idea to solve this problem :) thank you

Comment: @Don'tPanic it was all sorted. If I will win, why not share the blessings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of @Sammitch's excellent suggestion:

```
<?php

$ar = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '25-27-32-34-37-42', '11-17-18-22-33-41'];

function doesItMatch($arg1) {
    global $ar;

    $in = $arg1;

    $inA = explode("-", $in);
    sort($inA);
    $inB = implode("-", $inA);

    foreach ($ar as $elem) {
        if ($elem == $inB) {
            echo("found match for $arg1 : $elem\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    echo("found NO match for $arg1 !!!\n");
}

doesItMatch("01-05-24-30-35-36");
doesItMatch("05-30-01-36-35-24");
doesItMatch("01-05-24-30-35-33");

?>
```

Output:

```
found match for 01-05-24-30-35-36 : 01-05-24-30-35-36
found match for 05-30-01-36-35-24 : 01-05-24-30-35-36
found NO match for 01-05-24-30-35-33 !!!
```

Adapt into your overall code as required.

Comment: Thank you so much @landru27 . this is exactly what i needed. And also for the suggestion of Sammitch's. Thank you. Mark as answered :)

Comment: Don't use globals, pass the array in via function arguments.

Comment: @Sammitch : agreed, in general;  this is just demonstration code;  there are several rough edges that can be sanded down for proper incorporation into the overall target program

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding this as it is code I already had and it does what you want. I think it's a little more versatile than the other answer.

This can lookup :

- A string against a string
- A string against an array of strings
- An array of strings against another array of strings
- An array of strings against a string.

It returns an array with your needles as the keys and true or false as the value depending if it has been found or not.

You can add a third parameter to change the delimiter if you need something else than a dash.

```
<?php 
$ar = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '25-27-32-34-37-42', '11-17-18-22-33-41'];
$ar2 = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '05-30-01-36-35-24', '01-05-24-30-35-33'];
var_dump(sortAndMatch($ar2, $ar));
/*
 * array (size=3)
 *     '01-05-24-30-35-36' => boolean true
 *     '05-30-01-36-35-24' => boolean true
 *     '01-05-24-30-35-33' => boolean false
 */


/*
 * Sort 2 strings or arrays of strings and try to find $needles into $haystack.
 * Returns array($needle => bool);
 * $array[$needle] is true when it's found.
 * $array[$needle] is false when it isn't.
 */
function sortAndMatch($needles, $haystack, $delimiter = '-'){
    //Sort haystack
    foreach ((array)$haystack as $k => $combination){
        $haystack[$k] = explode($delimiter, $combination);
        sort($haystack[$k]);
    }
    //Sort and compare needles, builds $results
    foreach((array)$needles as $k => $needle){
        $needle= explode($delimiter, $needle);
        sort($needle);
        $results[$needles[$k]] = false;
        if(array_search($needle, $haystack) !== false){
            $results[$needles[$k]] = true;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot -- I'm up-voting it;  my answer is something I typed up on the fly, but yours makes for the better 'toolbox' function;  plus, I learned a new word (_polyvalent_) today!

Comment: @landru27 Well thanks, but you made notice that polyvalent is not an english word, it's actually french for "versatile, general purpose, etc". I removed that mistake from my answer, thank you again :).

Comment: If you are concerned about whether an input variable is an array or not and you are going to convert scalars to an array anyhow, then skip the conditional check and just force the conversion: `(array)$needles`  Effectively, this will leave arrays alone and convert strings/integers to an array -- no fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Your *haystack* set of numbers is already sorted, so that can remain unchanged.

You only need to explode, sort, and reimplode the *needle* numbers before checking against the *haystack* strings (this is what `in_array()` is for).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7K3M1))

```
function isMatch($haystack, $needle) {
    $nums = explode('-', $needle);         // explode
    sort($nums);                           // sort
    $needle = implode('-', $nums);         // implode
    return in_array($needle, $haystack);   // assess
}

$matches = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '25-27-32-34-37-42', '11-17-18-22-33-41'];  // already sorted
$givens = ['01-05-24-30-35-36', '05-30-01-36-35-24', '01-05-24-30-35-33'];

foreach ($givens as $given) {
    echo "$given : " , (isMatch($matches, $given) ? 'true' : 'false') , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
01-05-24-30-35-36 : true
05-30-01-36-35-24 : true
01-05-24-30-35-33 : false
```